# Undefined method in controller - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller called blogger:

```
class BloggerController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def favoritePosts
    @blogger = current_blogger
    @favorites = @blogger.favorite_posts
  end

  def suggestedPosts
    posts = Post.all
    @suggestedPosts = posts.similar_posts
  end

end
```

And in the Blogger model i have a method:

```
def similar_posts
 title_keywords = Post.body.split(' ')
  Post.all.sort do |post1, post2|
  post1_title_intersection = post2.body.split(' ') & title_keywords
  post2_title_intersection = post2.body.split(' ') & title_keywords
  post2_title_intersection.length <=> post1_title_intersection.length
 end
end
```

When i run the server its gives me an error:

```
undefined method `similar_posts' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa365029760>
```

After searching on stackoverflow i tried `def self.similar_posts`but it still gives the same error message. I also tried `new` in the controller like this `@suggestedPosts = posts.new.similar_posts` which still gives me the same error.
Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Comment: The problem is that you're using a Blogger.Method on a Post, there is no such method in Post. Try defining that on Post instead

Comment: `similar_posts` is defined on `post` object and not on `posts`, so do `@suggestedDevelopers = posts.map(&:similar_posts)`

Comment: you are trying to call `similar_posts` method on array of objects. Please try `posts.first.similar_posts`

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues happening at the same time.  The first is that you're using `posts` in your call, when you should be using something more like `post.blogger`.  The specific object depends on what your intent actually is.

The second issue is that you're making the call to `similar_posts` on the association, not on an individual record.  This can be resolved with a call to `each` on the association.

So, putting those together and looking at what you might have meant, I think that you might have intended this as your `suggestedPosts` method:

```
def suggestedPosts
  posts = Post.all
  @suggestedPosts = posts.map {|post| post.blogger.similar_posts }
end
```

I also changed the name of `@suggestedDevelopers` to `@suggestedPosts`, because I don't think that you meant 'developers' in this case.  This should give you something closer to what it appear you were trying for.